# QueryDSL - Predicate conversion : change root path and check structure

Tags: java, dto, predicate, querydsl, visitor-pattern

I'm using this awesome library, but I have a problem.

I'm implementing a DTO pattern, so I use another project to convert automaticaly an EJB to a DTO using naming conventions.

Then, I want to query the DTO and getting the real result (EJB query).

I implemented QueryDSL with JPAAnnotationProcessor on my ENTITIES, and the QuerydslAnnotationProcessor on my DTOs.

For example :

- An entity User(Long Id, String username, Site site)
- A DTO UserDto(Long id, String username, String siteName)

Converting objects is good, "siteName" automatically match "site.name".

And so, I put a QueryDSL Query like: `userDto.id.gt(20).and(userDto.username.like("a%")).and(userDto.siteName.like("%b"));`

I'm looking for a way to build the corresponding entity query

The only idea I got is to :

- Clone the Query
- Change the path "userDto" to "user"
- Verify each predicate to know if the property exists and if the type is matching

Any way to do that or to reach my goal?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Since this is still relevant and undocumented functionality, and since Timo's answer, while helpful, is very cryptic, here's how to do it:

First, extend `ReplaceVisitor`:

```
private class CustomReplaceVisior extends ReplaceVisitor<Void> {
    @Override
    public Expression<?> visit(Path<?> path, @Nullable Void context) {
        // The map Timo mentioned to transform paths:
        Map<Path<?>, Path<?>> map = Map.of(
            QUser.user.id, QUserDto.userDto.id,
            QUser.user.name, QUserDto.userDto.name
        );
        if (map.contains(path)) {
            return map.get(path);
        } else {
            return super.visit(path, context);
        }
    }
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
CustomReplaceVisior replaceVisitor = new CustomReplaceVisior();
Predicate userPredicate = QUser.user.id.eq(2).and(QUser.user.name.eq("Somename"));
Predicate userDtoPredicate = (Predicate) userPredicate.accept(replaceVisitor, null);
```

Comment: Excellent thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You will need to convert expressions in general. With a custom ReplaceVisitor you can for example override visit(Path expr, @Nullable Void context)

A generic way to do the path replacements would be to use a Map map to define the replacements:

```
if (map.contains(path)) {
    return map.get(path);
} else {
    return super.visit(path, context);
}
```

You can use your visitor like this:

```
Expression transformedExpression = expr.accept(visitor, null);
```